# How to move position of identify features window in QGIS 2.18.10

Tags: qgis, identify

When I select the "Identify Features" tool in the attribute toolbar, and then right click on a WMS layer, then the top of the appearing window is outside my screen and I cannot move it around.
How can I get this window to appear in a way, that it can be moved around?

[image: Screen shot of the window I get, when right clicking, when using the "Identify Feature" tool on WMS layer "Jordstykke"]

Comment: I have the same issue for some time now. If i drag the window horizontally wider, the top bar comes a bit into the visible area. Enough to move the window.

Comment: Thanks AndreJ. This works for me too. The question is then if there is a way to change how the window pops up, so I do not have to drag the window wider horizontally?

Answer (score 5):

I solved my own question by help from AndreJ. It seems that if I move the window and then close it, next time i use the tool, the window pops up - if not at the excactly same place - then at least so, that the top is inside the screen, so it can be immediatly moved around.